# ngModel does not work with ngView

Tags: angularjs

I want to two way bind with ng-model directive AFTER the ngview has loaded. Is this possible?

app.js

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        header = 'Header',
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    Header: <input type="text" ng-model="data.header"> {{data.header}}
</div>
```

Which works fine. What I want to do is do the exact same thing after ng-view

within ng-view I would put

```
{{data.header}}
```

and it would say "Header" but does not bind the data.

Hopefully I explained the problem clearly. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't bind to what? The scope of the `FormController` in the view, the scope of the view's controller or the view's parent's scope?

Answer (score -1):

here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/iZeMijiQ/2/edit)

#### In your script:

- declare `ngRoute` as a dependency
- use `$routeProvider` inside a config block to declare your routes
- I use inline template only for simplicity (In real apps I use **templateUrl**)

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/',{
    template: "Header: <input type='text' ng-model='data.header'> {{data.header}}",
    controller: "ctrl"
  });
});

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.data = {
    header : 'Header'
  };
});
```

#### In your html:

- Add `angular-route.js` to your scripts
- Add a `ng-view` directive